# HTML/CSS Templates

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently trying to figure out a way to create templates for a number of pages that look exactly the same. The only thing that is different is the content part.

I have worked with PHP and include() to separate several parts of my pages, but still need something that allows me to set a default layout and styling of an entire page since I will be  creating thousands of pages that are identical.

Please help me with some tips! Highly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you are not using a CMS? THOUSANDS of pages?

Comment: do you have something like a `header.php` and a `footer.php`?

Comment: yes ofcourse why is that strange? So what options are there with cms

Comment: Using a simple PHP include system for the header and footer of every page works, but if you are making thousands of pages you should really consider a CMS solution, which will make organizing your pages much more simple and also help your site grow in complexity over time. Plus you can harness community-submitted plugins for common tasks. If PHP is your preferred language, look at WordPress, Drupal, Concrete5, Expression Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> thousands of pages that are identical.

As stated in the comments, you should definitely go with a CMS (Content Management System)

**Main features of a CMS:**

1. Allow for a large number of people to share and contribute to stored data
2. Control access to data based on user role (i.e., define information users or user groups can view, edit, publish, etc.);
3. Facilitates storage and retrieval of data;
4. Control data validity and compliance;
5. Reduces duplicate inputs;
6. Simplify report writing;
7. Improve communication among users.
8. Define data as almost anything: documents, movies, texts, pictures, phone numbers, articles etc.
9. Content Management of Pages

   *Reference:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system

---

With that said, unless you want to spend countless hours studying and learning (which is not a bad thing) but it seems that you simply want to get this sophisticated website working, then a CMS is what you really need.

**Take a look at what i believe are the top CMS's out there:**

1. [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)
2. [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)
3. [Dupral](http://drupal.org/)

In a nutshell, you just need to get your Host, http://www.godaddy.com/  (not my personal favorite) but for simplicity; godaddy will install the CMS for you with a click of a button, it will setup everything and get you up and running! After that is complete, you can login via the administrator panel and play around with the settings to see how things work.

I would start with WordPress, heres a nice site to get you going once you have everything setup (assuming you go for Wordpress CMS)

- http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_start.htm
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout

Have fun! Hope this helps.